# ASP 80004005 error on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, ms-access, asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2

We are trying to run an ASP application on windows 2008 R2 standard (64 bit processor & iis 7.5). ASP application connects to MS Access database. IIS is running fine and Asp is running fine. But when ASP code tries to connect to MS-Access DB, its giving 500 error.

FilePath C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\XXXXXX\XXXXX_SECTIONS.ASP 
LineNumber 14 
CurrentStatement LevelTop.Open() 
ErrorCode 80004005

Error is coming exactly while opening connection to MS Access DB.

We checked with Process Monitor utility. I have attached the log file of process monitor. We assumed its a permission issue and granted all permissions, but still we are getting same error.

We even tried giving administration group user as IIS user. But still getting same issue.

**[Edit]**

Ok thanks joel. I am newbie to this environment.

I checked this link and installed this http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D.

Now I am getting this error
**ErrorCode: 800a0e7a 
Description: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed **

this is my connection string
**"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DBQ=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxx\App_Data\xxxxx.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"**

Set ThisSection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

ThisSection.ActiveConnection = ConnectionString
ThisSection.Source = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = " + Replace(ThisSection__MMColParam, "'", "''") + ""
ThisSection.CursorType = 0

ThisSection.CursorLocation = 2

ThisSection.LockType = 1

ThisSection.Open() ->** getting error exactly at this line**

Comment: This looks like a database engine error. What version of MS Access is the file, and does the server have the correct engine to open it? As I recall, Access 2007+ requires a special driver, not just the JET engine anymore.

Comment: "We assumed its a permission issue and granted all permissions" - can you detail what permissions you have granted and where?

Comment: Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is that the provider cannot be found.

Two sources of this error could be:

- Access is not installed
- Access 32bit is installed and IIS is looking for the 64bit version, or the other way around

There should be an error in your eventlog.

Also you could try a restart after the installation of the Access driver.

Comment: Do we need access? is driver not enough?

Comment: The driver in the link should be enough. Did you install 32 or 64 bit?